# Xcode 11 Crashing on pod command

Tags: xcode, xcode11

**Xcode : Version 11.0 (11A420a)**

Keep crashing whenever i perform a `pod install` command .

Can anyone explain the problem, or fix it ?

***PodFile***

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

def available_pods
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end

target 'PojectX' do
  use_frameworks!
  inherit! :search_paths
    available_pods
    end
  target 'PojectXTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    available_pods
   end
  target 'PojectY' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    available_pods
  end
  target 'PojectXUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    available_pods
  end
end
```

Comment: would you explain little bit more

Comment: like ?, it just crashes every time i execute pod install in the terminal .

Comment: share your Podfile  file content.

Comment: updated , question @NazmulHasan